# Random banner image with content on each page refresh Vs carousel

Tags: usability, sliders

On a website re-design, instead of using Content slider/carousel, I'm thinking of randomly showing new banner image with new content with each homepage refresh. [Because carousel are not good for UX](http://shouldiuseacarousel.com/)

**For example**

On of the banner with content

[image]

2nd banner (upon page refresh)

[image]

I know not all users would be able to notice all the banners but that is fine in my case. So there should not be an Accessibility issue with it.

- Would it be a bad UX?
- Is carousel better than randomly changing banner on page refresh?
- Or carousel with manual sliding would be much better?

Answer (score 1):

Carousels are only poor UX if they serve no use to the visitor. Similarly, in your scenario, only show a static banner or image carousel if it serves use to your visitors. If it is pointless and is of no use to your visitors, then don't use a static banner or carousel at all.

It isn't really a case of whether static banner vs carousel is best for UX. The answer to that will vary site to site, content to content, subject to subject, audience to audience.

Most websites stick a carousel on the homepage with no real purpose nor any evidence that it is more effective than not having one. The result being that is just annoys the visitor as it isn't useful.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the banners you have as examples, they look like the sort you would use in a carousel. The only time that makes sense to me to randomly show one banner or another is a small banner ad on the top/side of a page.

That said, it all depends on what you're trying to accomplish. If you are advertising the biggest selling points of a product, do one splash page will all of the banners' info, and links to more details in each category. For example, Apple does this with many of their products.

A current example of what I'm suggesting can be seen at http://www.apple.com/ipad/ - You get several sections roughly equivalent to one of your banners, each highlighting different bits about the product. Each one lets you explore that bit in more detail by clicking on it. It even ends with calls to action prompting visitors to shop online, visit a store, or contact them by phone.